# Estimating ARMA coefficients

Tags: time-series

Is recursive least square to estimate coefficients of ARMA(p,q) is equivalent to newton's method of finding coefficients using this -

$$C_{m+1}=C_m+(X^TV_mX)^{-1}X^T(Y-P_m)$$

---

EDIT:

I've used that equation in logistic regression to find coefficients. How to determine coefficients of ARMA(1,1) using following dataset -

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        Period & Value \\
        1 & 15 \\
        2 & 12\\
        3 & 19 \\
        4 & 21 \\
        5 & 17\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

---

[Here](http://siteresources.worldbank.org/DEC/Resources/Hevia_arma_mle.m) I've found a MATLAB function which uses Recursive Kalman Filter to estimate coefficients and [here](http://siteresources.worldbank.org/DEC/Resources/Hevia_ARMA_estimation.pdf) the process has been explained. It outputs $ar$ and $ma$ coefficients only and they are very different from those produced by R.

For a given 100 observations, it outputs -
$$ar: 0.9616\,\,\,\,ma: -179.4289\,\,\,\,\sigma: 0.0012 \,\,\,\, LL: -160.2952$$

with the same R (setting *include.mean = FALSE*) produced -
$$ar: 0.9590\,\,\,\,ma: 1.0000\,\,\,\,\sigma^2: 0.01309\,\,\,\, LL: 70.66$$

Comment: No.  In an ARMA model, you are modeling error terms, and what the error term is depends on what the form of the equation is.  So, in contrast to a typical Newton's method problem, where you are finding a solution to $y=f(x)$, the $y$ is changing as you fit the terms, so the iteration is nonlinear.

Comment: @Paul yes it worked in non-linear logistic regression

Comment: In a logistic regression, non-linear or not, the target (Y) does not change.  For a ARMA model, it does.

Comment: @Paul have a look at last section. Is he correct implementing kalman filter? Function itself is explanatory, no need to read explanation in second link.